# Restarting requests in case server crashes/restarts (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, server

I'm developing an application which processes asynchronous requests that takes on an average 10 minutes to finish. The server is written using **Spring Boot** and has 4 replicas and there's a **load balancer**. In case one of these server crashes while processing certain number of requests, I want these failed requests to restart on the remaining servers in a load balanced way.

Note: There's a common database in which we create a unique entry for every incoming request, and delete that entry when that request is processed successfully.

Constraints:

1. We can't wait for the server to restart.
2. There's no extra server to keep watch of these servers.
3. There's no leader/slave architecture among the servers.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use a message queue to handle the requests. I would recommend using Apache Kafka ([Spring for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/)) and propose the following solution:

1. Create 4 Kafka topics.
2. Whenever each of the 4 replicas receives a request, publish it on one of the 4 topics (randomly) instead of simply handling it.
3. Each replica will connect to Kafka and consume from one topic. If you let Kafka manage your topics, whenever one replica would crash, one of the other 3 will pick up its topic and start consuming requests in its place.
4. When the crashed replica restarts and connects to Kafka, it can start consuming again from its topic (this auto-balancing is already implemented in Kafka).

Another advantage of this solution is that you can, if you want to, stop using the database to store requests, as Kafka can act as your database in this case.

Comment: Perfect solution Sebastian Grigor, there's a catch though, we need to carefully handle the re balancing as the requests are long Async requests.